# How do I remove Underline from whole worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to remove all `Underline` in my worksheet and I would like to use a macro for this.

I could only find this code, which adds `Underline`.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate 
ActiveCell.Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
```

Comment: Macro recorder would have given you the code :)

Comment: I never thought about using a macro, I always select the cells in question and press CTRL-U twice (so it would underline everything and then remove it from everything).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Font.Underline = False
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim, this is perfect! Thank you so much!